# Does "Microsoft connector for oracle" support Oracle Wallet?

Tags: oracle, ssis, wallet

Does the "Microsoft connector for oracle" support Oracle Wallet? I am developing a SSIS package and created a connection, It seems I cannot connect to Oracle database which requires wallet. I keep getting the error: There was an error trying to establish an Oracle connection with the database server.

But my ODBC connection and sqlplus.exe can connect to the database perfectly.

Here are what I did:

- Installed oracleClient
- Installed wallet on the ssl_wallet folder
- Set environment variable set: ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN.
- Added the following to the tnsnames.ora (also tried using the WALLET_LOCATION)
  (SECURITY=
  (MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY=%ORACLE_HOME%\ssl_wallet)
  )
- Directory permissions are set correctly.
- Also tried using different version of oracleClient (32bit/64bit)
  Is there anything I missed?

Comment: "There was an error trying to establish an Oracle connection with the database server." - What is the error message?

Comment: This is the error message - "There was an error trying to establish an Oracle connection with the database server." The error message didn't provide details.

Comment: Which driver/provider do you use?

Comment: Microsoft Connector for Oracle via Visual Studio 2019